# raster diagrams in Matlab based on colormap

Tags: matlab, raster, colormap

I would like to create raster plots in Matlab based on my colormap *jet*. My colormap *jet* goes from -3 (blue) to +3 (red). So, I would like to plot the exact value of my data (e.g., +1.20) as the corresponding colour on the colormap *jet* (e.g., yellow).

However, at the moment I have a structure *A* of 66x900 double with values of 0 and 1, and a structure *B* of 66x900 double with different values in each cell (e.g., 0.21, +2.45, -1.09, etc.).

What I need to do is (1) to replace the values equal to 1 in structure *A* with the exact values of structure *B*. (2) I would need to plot the new structure (e.g., *C*) which is made of zeros and of values from structure *B*.

The tricky part is that in the raster plot, I would only need to plot with the colour of the colourmap *jet* the values/cells of structure *C* that were taken from structure *B* (including when those values were equal to zeros). Those cells that are equal to zero (those that were not replaced with values from structure *B*, as they were zeros already in structure *A*) need to become white pixels.

Example:

```
 Structure A
 0 **1** 0 0 0 **1** 0 **1** **1**   0     0 
 0 **1** 0 0 0   0   0 **1** **1**   0     0 
 0   0   0 0 0   0   0 **1** **1** **1** **1** 
 0   0   0 0 0   0   0 **1** **1** **1** **1** 

 Structure B
  1.2   **1.34**  2.34  1.33   1.43 **-2.99**  2.44  **1.27** **-2.76**   0.09      0.00 
 -2.3   **0.45**  2.99  2.01  -2.19   -0.98    0.56 **-1.87**  **2.14**   0.00     -0.98 
 -0.3     1.20   -0.17  1.2   -2.33   -0.67    1.23  **1.45**  **1.08** **1.01**  **0.00**
  1.11   -0.78   -1.66 -0.88   0.12   -1.04   -0.55  **1.32**  **1.34** **1.00**  **1.97** 

 Structure C
  0   **1.34**  0 0   0 **-2.99**  0  **1.27** **-2.76**   0         0 
  0   **0.45**  0 0   0    0       0 **-1.87**  **2.14**   0         0 
  0     0       0 0   0    0       0  **1.45**  **1.08** **1.01**  **0.00**
  0     0       0 0   0    0       0  **1.32**  **1.34** **1.00**  **1.97**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You want to multiply each element of the matrix A with its corresponding element in matrix B. This is done by adding a dot before the multiplication symbol (it also works for division and exponentials).

(2) *NaN* values are left blank in Matlab plot.

Here's a working example:

```
% Your data
A = [1 1 1 1 1 1; 0 0 1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 0 1 1; 1 1 1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 1 1 1];
B = [1 2 3 4 5 2; 5 4 0 0 0 4; 1 2 3 4 1 2; 5 5 5 3 3 3; 5 2 2 2 3 3; 5 1 5 3 4 4];
% Set all elements equal to zero to NaN so Matlab doesn't draw them
A(A==0) = NaN;
% This returns C(i,j) = A(i,j)*B(i,j) for all elements. 
% A*B would do a matrix multiplication
C = A.*B;
%Plot
pcolor(C)
```

Comment: It should be noted that the `NaN` pixels will not be rendered, and will appear therefore to have the color of whatever the axes background is.

Answer (score 0):

Random values:

```
a = double(randi([0 1],[4 11]));
b = rand(4,11);
```

Then:

```
idx = find(a == 1);
a(idx) = b(idx);
```

And here you have your colormap.

To obtain the white pixels (NaN will just make them transparent so they will take the background color):

```
a(a == 0) = 1;
```

Then, plot it:

```
colormap(gray);
pcolor(a);
```